# Validation of Smart Contract execution in Ethereum

Tags: mining, consensus

Now I understand that miners will run smart contracts in Ethereum and other nodes in the network will be checking the validity of the contract execution from [How is a node selected to run Smart Contract in Ethereum](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76866/how-is-a-node-selected-to-run-smart-contract-in-ethereum/)

In this case all these nodes are re-running the smart contract and then see whether the result is the same from the miner's execution? I guess not and I wonder how this smart contract validation is done exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the local nodes (not light nodes, full nodes only to be exact) do indeed execute all mined transactions. It is mainly because of this that an Ethereum full node is increasingly difficult to run, on the other hand it is needed for decentralization. A Medium article, [Life Cycle of an Ethereum Transaction](https://medium.com/blockchannel/life-cycle-of-an-ethereum-transaction-e5c66bae0f6e), has quite exact introductory information about Ethereum transactions.

Comment: I see. In this case the validating nodes don't get any GAS, right?

Comment: Correct, all gas from a transaction is received by the miner of the block containing the transaction.